# Is $f^2 \circ f=f \circ f^2$ true?

Tags: inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function from the set of real numbers to the same set with $f(x)=x+1$.

We write $f^{2}$ to represent $f \circ f and f^{n+1}=f^n \circ f$.

Is it true that $f^2 \circ f = f \circ f^2$?

Why?

Comment: Yes, they both map $x$ to $f(f(f(x)))$

Comment: What do you think? have you tried anything? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes that is true. Function composition is associative.

Comment: $f^2\times f=f\times f^2$ is not the same as $f^2 \circ f = f \circ f^2$

Comment: What is difference between x and ∘ ? @lhf

Comment: @NaySie, the cross is usually meant to denote a map induced by two copies of $f$ over the cartesian product of their domains, and the circle means composition ("one inside the other")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since composition of functions is *associative:*
$$
f\circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h
$$
then one may write
$$
f^2 \circ f = (f\circ f)\circ f = f\circ (f \circ f) = f\circ f^2.
$$

Comment: +1, nothing more to say.